# Is there a specific set of Hinduism emotions Gotham was attributing with those acupuncture needles?

Tags: analysis, props, gotham

In *Gotham* we meet The Shaman who was conditioning Bruce into emotionless puppet and used acupuncture needles with the Hindi words on the non-pointy end which Bruce called symbols:

[image][image]

They were clearly six and only three were readable:

1. भय - Fear
2. सुख - Amusement
3. रोष -  Wrath or rage

But is there some pattern of emotions here which can help us predict which three other needles were? Does it belong to some Hindu ideology emotion set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It describes the six main emotions:

1. **Anger** (रोष)
2. **Disgust**
3. **Fear** (भय)
4. **Happiness** (सुख)
5. **Sadness**
6. **Surprise**

[image: Wikipedia emotions diagram]

**Source**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion#Basic_emotions

So fill in with other Hindi words for each emotion as necessary! :D